# New CoreData version properties not showing up

Tags: ios, core-data

I am adding two properties to an existing CoreData entity. I have versioned my data model file and re-generated my entity so the properties now show up in both the header and code files. My application loads and reads from the database just fine, but when I try to assign a value to either of the new properties I get an error stating that the properties do not exist. The compiler is fine with them, but at runtime setting a breakpoint and inspecting the objects properties show that the new properties are indeed not there.

Other than the versioning of the data model file and regenerating the data model entities, is their anything else I need to configure to use the new data model properly? Do I need to point to the latest version of the data model somehow? When creating my persistent store I am using the light migration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When you add a new version of your data model, you still need to select which version your application should use. I guess that makes sense so you are able to work on a new version but not have your app use it right away. You can do this by selecting the top level data model file in the project navigator and then choosing the desired version in the file inspector.